# moment timezone now add one hour to local time

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a problem (which I didn't have before) when I try to format the date with local time:

```
   var dateStartFormat = "2021-1-8 08:00"
   var romeStart = moment.tz(dateStartFormat, "Europe/Rome");
   var romeStartFormat = romeStart.format();
```

romeStartFormat should give me: 2021-01-08T08:00:00+01:00
instead he adds an hour and gives me: 2021-01-08T**09:00:**00+01:00

I didn't change anything in the code, until a few days ago it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A few days ago" you were probably still in the end of december, so the timestamp would have been something like `"2020-12-28 08:00"`. Now in january you get a timestamp like `"2021-1-8 08:00"`, which is not a valid inputformat for momentjs. Momentjs expects either RFC2822 or ISO format as input, thus both day and month have to be given with two digits (and thus a leading 0 if < 10). Alternatively, you can also provide the formatspecifier for the timestamp you are passing in, so that momentjs can parse the date. When you run your code, you will probably notice a warning ...

Taking that into account, this snippet should return the expected result.

```js
let 
  date1 = "2021-01-08 08:00",
  date2 = "2021-1-8 08:00"
  
//use a proper formated timestamp  
let 
  start1 = moment.tz(date1, "Europe/Vienna"),
  format1 = start1.format();

//provide a format specifier
let 
  start2 = moment.tz(date2, "yyyy-M-D HH:mm", "Europe/Vienna"),
  format2 = start2.format();

console.log(format1);
console.log(format2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.32/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: perfect, now i solved. it works even if i leave rome instead of vienna.

Answer (score 0):

you should add format to `momnet.tz()`

```
var dateStartFormat = "2021-1-8 08:00"
var romeStart = moment.tz(dateStartFormat, "YYYY-M-D HH:mm" , "Europe/Rome");
var romeStartFormat = romeStart.format();
```

Comment: mmmm so I correct the time, it works, but then I get the date wrong ... he doesn't accept it

Comment: If you copy your answer from another one, you should at least do it correctly. First of all, the format specifiers for days and months are `D` and `M` (instead of `d` and `m`) respectively. Furthermore, you got the order wrong. Your format would result in the 1st of August instead of 8th of January.